# How to access multiple tables in using flask-sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two classes in two separate files: mymodels.py holds database models and resources.py is for resource access. 
In resources.py i have class for user registration which is used to register new users, which calls UserModel class from mymodels. I want to store registration data into two separate tables:
login table for storing username/password and users table for storing other user details.
Could you please advice how can i modify my code to access two tables?

```
mymodels.py
************
class UserModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'login'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(120), unique = True, nullable = False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable = False)
    ...........


resources.py
*************
    from mymodels import UserModel  
    class UserRegistration(Resource):
        def post(self):
            data = parser.parse_args()
            new_user = UserModel(
                username = data['username'],
                password = data['password']
            )
          ..............
```

Comment: Can't you define another table called UserDetail and instantiate it insider class UserRegistration too?

Comment: Just like how you are doing it with UserModel instantiation, below that new_user code, instantiate UserDetail with correct parameters.